# Cypress open/run with specific browser version

Tags: browser, cypress

I would like to open/run a cypress test with a specific Chrome browser version, I found it is possible to force to chrome with `--browser chrome` or even with beta with `--browser chrome:beta` but did not found how to run with a specific version, like for instance `--browser chrome:94`.

Anybody knows if it is possible ? And if yes, how to do it ?

Edit: as mention in an answer there is the possibility to use `--browser /path/to/browser` but what I want, if possible of course, is something automatic that does not need an installation of specific browser version before run.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem possible to install multiple versions of chrome (apart from chrome:beta and chrome:canary). chrome:stable automatically updates itself on the machine.

In any case you want to do it without installing, Docker is one way to go.

There's a range of images [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/browsers)

```
cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome89-ff86  
cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89  
cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93       
cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome97-ff96   
cypress/browsers:node16.13.0-chrome95-ff94
```

Be aware that Cypress and Node versions that are compatible with different chrome versions, as indicated [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/included)

```
cypress/included:8.5.0  cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89
cypress/included:8.6.0  cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89
cypress/included:8.7.0  cypress/browsers:node14.17.0-chrome91-ff89
cypress/included:9.0.0  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.1.0  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.1.1  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.2.0  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.2.1  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.3.0  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.3.1  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
cypress/included:9.4.1  cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
```

So if you try to run Cypress@9.4.1 with chrome@91 you may get unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it and see if it suits what I need

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do that by passing the path of old browser installed on your system as mentioned in the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers#Launching-by-a-path)

```js
cypress run --browser /usr/bin/chromium

cypress open --browser /usr/bin/chromium
```

You can also create multiple commands under your `package.json` like:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "chrome:95": "cypress run --browser path to chrome 95",
    "chrome:96": "cypress run --browser path to chrome 96",
    "chrome:97": "cypress run --browser path to chrome 97"
  }
```

Then directly run your tests like:

```js
npm run chrome:95
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that (and I'll edit my question) but I would like something automatic that runs with specific version without having to install it

Comment: I have updated my answer. Another way to achieve what you are looking for. I am pretty sure cypress doesn't allow out of the box what you are looking for. Neither I know of any service or plugin using using which you can achieve this. In any case if you find a better approach to do this, please add an answer, I would also like to learn.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it, indeed it seems the best way with provided tools

Answer (score 0):

I use docker to do this. To prevent any interference with your working directory I'd copy the files from your repo to the container. But one after the other. First find the docker image with the brower versions you want to use from the official cypress repo

https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/browsers/tags

After that start the container

```bash
docker run -it <your-image> /bin/bash
```

copy your repo over to the container (I am assuming you are running this command from your repos root folder now and from outside the container)

```bash
docker cp . <container-id>:/app
```

In your running container navigate to the /app folder then install cypress again (as /root/.cache will be missing) and run your tests

```bash
cd /app
npx cypress install --force
npx cypress run --headless --browser <your choice>
```

I'd always choose this over installing multiple browser versions on your machine and you will also less likely hit additional issues when trying to integrate your tests into a pipeline because you can just use the same container as you have here.